# How to pass dynamic values for component in Clover ETL Graph?

Tags: sql, etl, clover, cloveretl

I have tried in passing the values to ETL Graph in CloverETL for ETL process, but I need to pass the values dynamically in the Clover ETL for Graph. Can anyone say how to pass the values dynamically??

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you have Corporate edition you could start graphs and pass dynamically calculated values as parameters into them really easily with Jobflows (see ExecuteGraph http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/topic/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/executegraph.html
If you have smaller edition, you could probably do it with call to API, but it is not so comfortable and getting results back would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

First go to Parameter ---> Edit ---> Add New Parameter ,
Give a Name
then save it.
Then go to Reformat or any component you need.

In Transformations part add new transformation and put `getParamValue("Name")`

and assign the value in field part with data type and save it.

After that run the package.

when you run package it ask you to put parameter value.

It takes that value and processing as per requirement.